# SQL exception Parameter index out of range

Tags: mysql, sql, parameter-passing

I'm sending 4 values for the sql query through a jaggery script. Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT full_name , sum( amount ) AS total 
    FROM hourlyusage , user
    WHERE   DAY = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL ? HOUR ) ) 
            AND HOUR BETWEEN HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL ? HOUR ) ) 
            AND HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) )
            AND hourlyusage.userIp = user.ip_address 
            AND (user.full_name LIKE '%?%' OR user.user_name LIKE '%?%')  GROUP BY full_name
```

But it gives an exception like this. 
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

What would be the reason for that?

Comment: You are executing this query by using Prepared statment, Right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT full_name , sum( amount ) AS total 
    FROM hourlyusage , user
    WHERE   DAY = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL ? HOUR ) ) 
            AND HOUR BETWEEN HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL ? HOUR ) ) 
            AND HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) )
            AND hourlyusage.userIp = user.ip_address 
            AND (user.full_name LIKE ? OR user.user_name LIKE ?)  GROUP BY full_name
```

You cannot use wildcard in the sql query so try to remove the wildcard from the sql and add it to the value.As you have done **'%?%'** in sql says that you need global match.Do that in your value not in sql query.